# How to define delta in a PDA

Tags: tuples, computation-theory, delta, pushdown-automaton

I'm a little confused about PDA's and how to define the tuple. I have the language L = { 0^n1^n | n >= 0 } and I know that PDA's are six tuple with Q, sigma, gamma, delta, q0, and F. I know how to define all of them except delta.

```
Q = ['q1', 'q2', 'q3', 'q4'] 
sig = ['0', '1']
gam = ['0', '$']
delta = ?
q0 = 'q1'
F = ['q1', 'q4']
```

Can anyone help me understand how delta is defined?

Answer (score 1):

One transition in a PDA is made of the tuple `(s, i, A, d, B)`, where:

- `s` is the source state that the automaton must **currently** be at to be able to use the transition
- `i` `(i in Sigma or epsilon)` has to be the **current** character in the input to be able to use the transition, and it will be **read** from the input if the transition is used
- `A` `(A in Gamma*)` are the **symbols** that has to be on **top** of the stack to be able to use the transition
- `d` is the destination state (where the automaton will move **to** by the use of the transition)
- `B` `(B in Gamma*)` are the symbols that will **replace** A on the **top** of the stack, if the transition is used.

The transitions for this language are written in the [example section in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushdown_automaton#Example).